# Creating character text box in html

Tags: html, user-interface, textbox

I have a requirement of creating text box which will have columns and every columns will accommodate a single character .

Like the image of text box is :-

[image]

Is there any simple way to do it or i have to create a set of separate text boxes to accomplish the task?
Can anyone tell me the way to create it ?
I have googled a little bit for the solution but havent found anything helpful.

Please help me with this.

Thanks and regards

Comment: I see only one row in the image, no columns. Well, very reduced-case columns. Are the boxes really supposed to appear as matrix-like, in columns? And should they be text input boxes somehow, or just for display of character data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a jquery and insert a dynamic text box at run time on some event. This dynamic text box is with maxlength=1.

Comment: ok so that means i have to insert several text boxes with maxlength 1 to ahcieve the task.is that right?.Thanks for the fast reply too :)